# How to install phpMailer on azure Web App

Tags: php, azure, curl, phpmailer, sendgrid

I've been researching lots of solutions in mail services for azure and I decided that the best solution for me is with phpMailer. I already tried to use the sendgrid API but I want to utilize the Ajax post method with jquery/javascript.

I have also found another solution that involves CURL. But the I'm getting an error on

```
Dotenv::load(__DIR__);
```

The error seems to be from sendGrids own php-files.

How do I solve any of these issues on azure.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
Dotenv::load(__DIR__);
$sendgrid_apikey = getenv('YOUR_SENDGRID_APIKEY');
$sendgrid = new SendGrid($sendgrid_apikey);
$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
$pass = $sendgrid_apikey;
$template_id = '<your_template_id>';
$js = array(
  'sub' => array(':name' => array('Elmer')),
  'filters' => array('templates' => array('settings' => array('enable' => 1, 'template_id' => $template_id)))
);

$params = array(
    'to'        => "test@example.com",
    'toname'    => "Example User",
    'from'      => "you@youremail.com",
    'fromname'  => "Your Name",
    'subject'   => "PHP Test",
    'text'      => "I'm text!",
    'html'      => "<strong>I'm HTML!</strong>",
    'x-smtpapi' => json_encode($js),
  );

$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);
// Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $sendgrid_apikey));
// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

// print everything out
print_r($response);

?>
```

Best wishes, Stanner

Comment: You're saying you want to use PHPMailer, but you're not using it?

Comment: Yes I wish to use it. I'm just confused about how to install the libary on azure web app so ive posted another solution if you know why i'm getting the error. I have checked the phpinfo No phpmailer libary unless i'm looking for wrong for the wrong variable.

Comment: PHPMailer is an external library, it's not part of PHP. You can get it from [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and upload it along with your other PHP libraries & files, or (the recommended way) load it using [composer](https://getcomposer.org). Base your code on the examples provided with it.

Answer (score 0):

`phpMailer` is a mail server which need the PHP runtime enables the SMTP server, and it requires to enable the 25 port. Unfortunately, we don't have the permission to do this on Azure Web Apps.

I suggest you to use the 3rd part mail server to send emails from your applications on Azure Web Apps. On Azure, you can easily use SendGrid to satisfy this, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-sendgrid-php-how-to-send-email/ for more info.